# Как вмешаться в чужой js?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, code-injection

Вопрос таков, нужно изменить некие ссылки на странице, но к сожалению они хранятся не в виде html, а внутри js и потом только подтягиваются по клику.
Можно ли изменить уже написанный js?
Или есть ли возможность при загрузке к примеру с помощью расширения Tampermonkey отключить js скрипт который грузится и подключить свой, аналогичный, только чуть-чуть измененный. 
Если да, то подскажите, как это можно сделать:)

Comment: Все можно. Вопрос в том что обрабатывает клик. Именованная функция, вызываемая именно по имени или безимянный обработчик повешенный на событие

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, как именно работает скрипт, и что именно требуется.

Если же просто заменить ссылки, тогда можно добавить кнопку внутрь имеющихся кнопок, и отменять "пропагацию" евента вверх . Пример:

```
<div onclick="alert('Оригинальная кнопка нажата')">
  <span onclick="var event = arguments[0] || window.event; alert('Инжектная кнопка нажата'); event.stopPropagation()">То что было раньше в кнопке.</span>
</div>
```

При этом, если вместо div елемент a - тогда нужно отменить евент. Так же, если нужно получить ссылку, всё зависит от конкретной ситуации.

Пример на JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z4ospxem/

Инжектить свой елемент можно многими способами. Самый простой из них:

```
document.getElementById("elementToInject").innerHTML = ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4ospxem/1/

Comment: Если бы проблема была во внешних ссылках. Дело в том что ссылка автозагрузки находится внутри js скрипта во время выполнения. Она не находится на самой странице. Все что касается html вообще никакой проблемы не составляет. Но проблема сама в том что бы изменить данные которые хранятся в переменной js. В том файле который подключается на сайт.

Comment: Переменная, как я понимаю, не глобальная ? И как я понял, вам нужно получить саму ссылку ?

Comment: Как вариант, это через https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest , если можете написать свое дополнение к гугл хрому . Думаю можно найти плагины которые разрешают загружать код как код плагина.

Comment: Да, не глобальная. если бы была, было бы проще. И нужно получить ссылку. Большая проблема в том что коде сжат и нечетабелен. То есть все название изменены на набор букв.

Comment: В каком смысле, загружать код как код плагина?

Comment: И чем этот способ отличается от способа через Tampermonkey ?

Comment: Как вариант, это найти присвоение window.location на какую-то переменную и заменить на myFunctionToOverrideLocation(url). Отличие этого способа тем, что при данном методе вы можете изменить скрипт который загружается с сайта .